# JPA Bi-directional Remove

Tags: java, jpa

In OpenJPA, I try to remove an entity with a bi-directional mapping to another entity. I did "find" and then "remove" but I have got an exception of "Encountered deleted object". Can someone provide me a working example?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Order")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderPK pk;
...

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="order")
    private Invoice invoice;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Invoice")
public class Invoice implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private InvoicePK pk;
...
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn   
    private Order order;
}

@Embeddable
public class OrderPK implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private Date date;
...
}

@Embeddable
public class InvoicePK implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private Date date;
...
}
```

First, I add them in a single transaction and commit:

```
Order order = new Order(...);
order.set...
Invoice invoice = new Invoice(...);
invoice.set...
order.setInvoice(invoice);
invoice.setOrder(order);
em.persist(order);
```

Then when I try to remove the order, I expect the invoice will be gone too:

```
Order order = em.find(Order.class, orderPK); em.remove(order);
```

but I have an exception instead saying:

```
Encountered deleted object "org.apache.openjpa.enhance.Order$pcsubclass-
Order-OrderPK@92882281" in persistent field "Invoice.order" of managed 
object "Invoice$pcsubclass-InvoicePK@92882281" during flush.
```

Comment: Could you provide more context as in with which datastore you are using JPA? Some feature support might vary. But I would imagine, there would be a Cascade.REMOVE kind of annotation in entity defination, do you have one?

Comment: Post some code - entities, mappings, EntityManager operations, etc.

Comment: If I use `Query q = em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM ORDER WHERE ...");` everything turns out ok.

Comment: And how does your `OrderPK` and `InvoicePK` look like?

Comment: My PK are composite keys. In this example, it may not look reasonable.